# Sqlite SEE Product Activation Key

Tags: sqlite

We just bought a license for the [SQLite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see). In the documentation it says:

> If you deploy the SQLite encryption extension as a DLL or shared
> library then you must first activate the library by invoking:
>
> `sqlite3_activate_see("7bb07b8d471d642e");`
>
> The argument is your product activation key. The activation key is
> available as plain-text in the source code so you can clearly see what
> it is. The purpose of the activation key is to prevent one of your
> customers from extracting the SQLite library and using it separately
> from your application. Without knowledge of the activation key, which
> only you should know, your users will be unable to access the
> encryption features.

Where do I find the product activiation key that I have to use here (we only receivedy user name and password after buying the license)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I understand that now. We can define our own key as the product activation key and put it both in our source code and in the SQLite source code here (replacing the default/placeholder key):

```
SQLITE_API void sqlite3_activate_see(const char *zPassPhrase){
  encryptionEnabled = strcmp(zPassPhrase, "7bb07b8d471d642e")==0;
}
```